# Backbone toJSON not rending

Tags: json, backbone.js, model, render

I am a complete n00b to Backbone.js, and have only been working with it for a few days. I am attempting to fetch JSON data to populate the model, and in this scenario I have two models that I need to generate. Here is the sample JSON I have been working with:

JSON

```
{
"status": "200",
"total": "2",
    "items":
    [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Here is another name",
        "label": "Label for test",
        "description": "A description for more information.",
        "dataAdded": "123456789",
        "lastModified": "987654321"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Name of item",
        "label": "Test Label",
        "description": "This is just a long description.",
        "dataAdded": "147258369",
        "lastModified": "963852741"
    }]
}
```

Backbone JS

```
// MODEL
var Service = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    label: '',
    description: '',
    dateAdded: '',
    dateModified: ''
}
});
var service = new Service();

// COLLECTION
var ServiceList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Service,
    url: "./api/service.php",
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.items;
    }
});
//
var serviceList = new ServiceList();
var jqXHR = serviceList.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log("Working!");
                console.log(serviceList.length);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Failed to fetch!");
    }
});


// VIEW for each Model
var ServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.widget-content'),
    tagName: 'div',
    template: _.template($('#service-template').html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection);
        this.$el.html('');
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            self.$el.append(self.template(model.toJSON()));
        });
        return this;
    }
});
//
var serviceView = new ServiceView({
    collection: serviceList
});
console.log(serviceView.render().el);
```

html

```
<div class="widget-content">
    <!-- Template -->
    <script type="text/template" id="service-template">
        <div><%= name %></div>
    </script>
</div>
```

When I console log the serviceList.length I get the value 2, so I believe the JSON object is fetched successfully. I also get the "Working!" response for success too. However, in the view I am showing an empty object, which gives me an empty model.

I am still trying to understand the best way to do this too. Maybe I should be using collections for the "items" and then mapping over the collection for each model data? What am I doing wrong? Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems.  First, you want to remove `serviceList.reset(list)`.  Your collection should be populated automatically by the call to `fetch`.  (In any case the return value of `fetch` is not the data result from the server, it is the "jqXHR" object).

```
var serviceList = new ServiceList();
var jqXHR = serviceList.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
        console.log("Working!");

        // this is the asynchronous callback, where "serviceList" should have data
        console.log(serviceList.length);
        console.log("Collection populated: " + JSON.stringify(collection.toJSON()));
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Failed to fetch!");
    }
});
// here, "serviceList" will not be populated yet
```

Second, you probably want to pass the `serviceList` instance into the view as its "collection".  As it is, you're passing an empty model instance into the view.

```
var serviceView = new ServiceView({
    collection: serviceList
});
```

And for the view, render using the collection:

```
var ServiceView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...

    initialize: function() {
        // render when the collection is reset
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log("Collection rendering: " + JSON.stringify(this.collection.toJSON()));

        // start by clearing the view
        this.$el.html('');            

        // loop through the collection and render each model
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            self.$el.append(self.template(model.toJSON()));
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/W5XeW/7/) a Fiddle demo.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the fetch understanding. I see that the JSFiddle does work, but when replicating I still get an empty model. I'm confused by why you suggested to remove the serviceList reset, but added it in the JSFiddle?

Comment: @user3362859 I added it to the Fiddle just as a mock -- typically you use `collection.reset` when you have the data already on hand, and `collection.fetch` to send a request to the server.  You don't need to use both, though ...

Comment: That makes sense. I see the jqXHR has the stored data that we fetched, but I do not see it passed into the collection. This could be why the model is still empty. Do I need to pass in the jqXHR to the collection?

Comment: I updated the post to show the code I have with your revisions. Can you see what is causing the empty model?

Comment: @user3362859 yes -- the "service" object in your example is just an empty model.  It has no connection at all to the data fetched into the "serviceList" collection.

Comment: @user3362859 that's the point of the second part of my answer -- your data is in the "serviceList" collection, so presumably that is what should be passed into the view.

Comment: I feel like I'm so close to getting this to work, but keep hitting a brick wall. I understand the data is in the serviceList collection, and I have passed in the serviceList collection into the view. Then we looped through the collection passing in the model, which I understood would populate the model with the data from the serviceList collection...except I get an empty model?

Comment: @user3362859 I think the last step is to make sure you're passing the collection, instead of the empty model, into the view:  `var serviceView = new ServiceView({ collection: serviceList });`

Comment: @user3362859 if that doesn't work, I would add logging to make sure that the data is correct inside `fetch`, and then inside `parse`.

Answer (score 0):

The call `serviceList.fetch` is made asynchronously, so when you try `console.log(serviceList.length);` the server has not yet send it's response that's why you get the the value 1, try this :

```
var list = serviceList.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log(serviceList.length);
        console.log("Working!");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Failed to fetch!");
    }
});
```